# which partition should be set active in windows 10?

Tags: windows, partitioning, c

I accidentally made C: as active, but don't know which one was before.
Should I set the System Reserved as active?

System Reserved - (System, Primary Partition)
Win-10 (C:) -  (Boot, Page File, *Active*, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)

Comment: Is your system currently booting into Windows?  If you can indeed boot into Windows, then you shouldn't change anything, about the partitions since their configuration are currently correct.

Comment: the thing is that the C was not active before I set it....so I changed it my mistake.

Comment: Your question indicates you don't actually know if it was set to be active or not.  If *Your system boots then you shouldn't make any additional changes*

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's article
[Active](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-diskconfiguration-disk-modifypartitions-modifypartition-active):

> Active specifies whether to mark the partition as active. On a
>   BIOS-based system, the active partition is the partition the system
>   will boot to. This partition must be a primary partition.
>
> On a Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI)-based system, this
>   setting is not used. The system will always boot to the EFI System
>   Partition (ESP). If Active is set for this partition type, it is
>   ignored.

So if you are booting with UEFI, which most reasonably new computers do nowadays,
then it is unimportant whether Active is set or not, as it is always ignored.